# What's the difference between complaints 不満 不平 文句?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, word-usage

I tried reading explanations in Japanese on hinative, but they tend to use one of these words to describe the other two.

Usually I only distinguish formal complaints (苦情) and verbal informal complaints, and apparently there are at least three types of informal complaints in Japanese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **不満**
  *Dissatisfaction* or *discontent*, as literal as it reads. This word doesn't necessarily mean *complaint*, because it stands for an emotion and doesn't need to be expressed.
- **不平**
  *Complaint about bad, undue, or unfair **treatment***. In theory, it doesn't need to be expressed either, but modern usage seems mostly so. We also have a combined word 不平不満 when people grow really bitter and twisted.
- **文句**
  It's the easiest word among them that means *something to say against*. Yes, it widely covers from *complaint* to *disapproval*.

  > 彼の実力を認めたくないやつらが文句をつけているにすぎない。
  >   *Just those who don't want to acknowledge his ability are criticizing it.*
- **苦情**
  *Complaint for remedy of the situation*. I don't think it's particularly "formal" but imaginably you say this more to officials (but also to companies for their products etc).

---

**PS**

- **不服**
  The "formal complaints" reminded me of this term, which literally means "insubordination" and used when you file objections to administrative decisions: 不服[申立]{もうしたて} *motion for complaint*.

Answer (score 4):

不満 also means "unsatisfactory" (as in "unsatisfactory score"), and 文句 also means "line; phrase" (as in "catchphrase").

When they mean "complaint", 不平 and 不満 are almost completely interchangeable. The focus of 不平/不満 is unhappy *feeling* rather than words. 不満 is relatively more common, and 不平 is often used along with 不満 ([不平不満](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8D%E5%B9%B3%E4%B8%8D%E6%BA%80)). 文句 focuses on verbal phrases of complaint you actually express. Therefore you can say 不平/不満を抱える, 不平/不満を漏らす or 不平/不満な顔, but not <sup>×</sup>文句を抱える, <sup>×</sup>文句を漏らす nor <sup>×</sup>文句な顔.