# What is the difference between 文句 and 苦情?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words

They both mean 'complaint', but there is a slight difference between them, right? If someone could explain the difference and provide some example sentences it would be great.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57487/9831